# Visual Studio 2017 Unit Test Automatic Setup

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

Adding a Native Unit Test project to a 2017 Visual Studio Solution, VS2017 Wizard does not add the *Unit Test* functionality automatically in the project settings ie `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest` for Include & Library directories, the path of the Project to be tested, etc.

Also, including the functions I want to test in the TestUnit project ie `Component1` fails once again but this time in the linking phase, saying that it could not find the Component1 object or library.

So, currently, I have to add all this stuff manually, ie Adding the UnitTest path inside the *VC++ Include/Library Directories* of the `Configuration Properties` of the project, adding *Obj Dependencies* in the Linker's `Input` etc. That's ok but the question is Can I fix this to work automatically as I used before?

PS: This was not always the case. Before I add/uninstall some features using the VS installer, it worked just fine.

[image]

Comment: I noticed that there is [a similar thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2019-rc-cannot-open-include-file-cppunittesth-w/472005). Try the latest Visual Studio 2022 and create a  new unit test project. Will the problem occur again?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFTThanks but I own the enterprise edition 2017, so ver 2022 needs to be paid again. Anyway, can different versions co-exist?

Comment: `can different versions co-exist` Yes.